# Transitive closure of R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Given the data set

[image]

> I have to find the connectivity relation $R^\infty$ and write it as a
>   Boolean matrix.

I've found the connectivity relation to be
\begin{align*}
R^\infty = \{  
  &(A,A), (A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (A,E), (A,F), (A,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(B,A), (B,B), (B,C), (B,D), (B,E), (B,F), (B,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(C,A),(C,B),(C,C), (C,D),(C,E),(C,F),(C,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(D,A),(D,B),(D,C),(D,D),(D,E),(D,F),(D,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(E,A),(E,B),(E,C),(E,D),(E,E),(E,F),(E,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(F,A),(F,B),(F,C),(F,D),(F,E),(F,F),(F,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(G,G),(G,I),(G,J), \\[0.5em]
  &(H,A),(H,B),(H,C),(H,D),(H,E),(H,F),(H,H), \\[0.5em]
  &(I,G), (I,I),(I,J), \\[0.5em]
  &(J,G),(J,I),(J,J) \} 
\end{align*}

The Boolean matrix will then be

$$M_{R} = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\[0.5em]
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.5em] 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\[0.5em]
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\[0.5em]
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I feel like this is wrong though. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Draw a crude map with every one of these locations. Draw an an arrow from each one on the left margin to each one on the upper margin to which it is directly connected.  See if there's any place where you can say "You can't get there from here."

Comment: It might be easier to fill in the original matrix one stage at a time until there are no changes.

Comment: Your matrix looks correct. Basically two disconnected groups.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Note that if you interchange Genève and Hamburg in the ordering of the cities, your matrix becomes $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}\;,$$ making the separation into two $R^\infty$-equivalence classes very obvious.